# submitScoreGPGS does not work with AsyncTask

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to get the `Google Play Services` working as following using AsyncTaks:

1 - The Login Dialog is only displayed when the user click on the leaderboard button which call the method `loginGPRS()` below;

2 - An ansync task is then executed which call the startLoginGRPS() method on the `onPreExecute`

3 - [Here is the problem] Once he is logged in, I want to call the methods `submitScoreGPRS()` and `getLeaderBoardGPRS()` in `onPostExecute` method, but the leaderboard dialog is never opened...

Here is the relevant source code:

```
@Override
public void loginGPGS() {
    try {
            MyAsyncTask asyncTask_a = new MyAsyncTask();
            asyncTask_a.execute();
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
    }

}

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    String errorMsg;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        startLoginGPGS();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... v) {

            return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        if(success){
            submitScoreGPGS(bestScore);
            getLeaderboardGPGS();
        }
    }
}



public void startLoginGPGS() {
    try {
    //  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    //      public void run() {
                gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
    //      }
    //  });
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
    }

}   

@Override
public void submitScoreGPGS(int score) {
    if(getSignedInGPGS()){
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                getString(R.string.leaderboard1_id), score);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you trace your code??

Write something like...

Log.d("Trace","Point X"):

In the doInBackground method just before the return true, another one in the onPostExecute method just before the if and inside the if.

Take a look at your Logcat and come back...

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing your method on the UI thread, because `onPostExecute()` runs on the UI thread and your method has network execution..

You should move your method to the `doInBackground()` method